# Getting an attribute error in Python

Tags: python

I know that there are a few post on Python attribute errors but I cannot find anything to help solve my issue or how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, ID_number, dept, job_title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__ID_number = ID_number
        self.__dept = dept
        self.__job_title_number = job_title

    #set methods
    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_ID_number(self,ID_number):
        self.__ID_number = ID_number
    def set_dept(self,dept):
        self.__dept = dept
    def set_job_title(self,job_title):
        self.__job_title = job_title


    #get methods    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_ID_number(self):
        return self.__ID_number
    def get_dept(self):
        return self.__dept
    def get_job_title(self):
        return self.__job_title

def main():

    emp1 = Employee("Susan Myers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President")
    emp2 = Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, "IT", "Programmer")
    emp3 = Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774, "Manufacturing", "Engineer")

    print("Information for employee 1:")
    print("Name:",emp1.get_name())
    print("ID:",emp1.get_ID_number())
    print("Department:",emp1.get_dept())
    print("Job Title:",emp1.get_job_title())

main()
```

> The traceback that I get is: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users....", line 48, in 
>       main()
>   File "C:/Users....", line 41, in main
>       print("Job Title:",emp1.get_job_title())
>   File "C:/Users....", line 29, in get_job_title
>       return self.__job_title 
>   AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute '_Employee__job_title'

Comment: Getter and setter methods are not needed in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `__init__`, you use `self.__job_title_number = job_title`, but then in `get_job_title` you use `self.__job_title`, which at this point hasn't been set.

You need to make your variable name consistent across all uses.

Answer (score 0):

In your init function inside your class you have job title as `self.__job_title_number` but in the getter function you return `self.__job_title`. You have to change one of these so they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the member in the constructor

Must change

```
self.__job_title_number = job_title
```

to

```
self.__job_title = job_title
```